Why the name "suppressed carrier" for the DSB-SC modulation?
In DSB-SC modulation, there is no discrete component at the carrier frequency, I mean no impulse at the carrier frequency, but when you look at its spectrum, you will find that it spans the frequency range from -B to +B, centered at the carrier frequency, with bandwidth 2B, where B is the information signal bandwidth. Thus, there is a value for the amplitude spectrum at the carrier frequency, I mean that it is one of the frequency components of the modulated signal, but not in the form of an impulse, then why we say that the carrier is suppressed, and what does the value of the amplitude spectrum at the carrier frequency represent? When we multiply the information signal by the carrier, all the frequency components of the message signal are shifted up by the carrier frequency, and thus the zero frequency will be shifted to the carrier frequency, which confirms that the carrier frequency represents of the frequency components of the modulated signal.

DSB-SC (Double Sideband Suppressed Carrier) was named in contrast to large carrier AM modulations, where the carrier was transmitted for no other purpose than to provide a carrier in the receiver for demodulation (via envelope detection). Thus the transmit power efficiency was degraded since there was no information content in that carrier signal that was transmitted.
With DSB-SC, unless we send information specifically at the carrier (via a DC offset in our modulation signal), the carrier will be suppressed and thus the modulation technique provides greater transmit power efficiency in terms of power transmitted and information conveyed.

I don't think Fessenden was thinking "oh, we're providing a synchronized carrier" back in 1906.  In fact, in 1906 there's a good chance that there was enough phase modulation that the carrier was not, in fact, well synchronized.  Certainly that was the case when he was attempting AM with a spark-gap transmitter.

Yes true- providing a carrier for demodulation would be more accurate

What about the case of sending information specifically at the carrier via a DC offset in the information signal? there may be a large value for the amplitude spectrum of the modulated signal at the carrier frequency, what does this value represent? Can we say that the carrier is suppressed in this case? What is the difference between this case and the DSB transmitted carrier case in which there is an impluse at the carrier frequency?

@Noha that is what I am saying in my second paragraph — when the carrier is present in DSB-SC modulation (assuming no imbalances in the modulator or demodulator, so let’s assume the perfect technical case) then that carrier component represents transmitted information. When there is no DC offset in the modulated signal for DSB-SC, the carrier will be suppressed. This is in contrast to Large Carrier AM and is why we make that distinction.

When there is an unintended impulse (in the frequency domain) at the carrier frequency for DSB-SC modulation that wasn’t due to an offset in the modulation signal, it is perceived as an offset and thus creates an offset error (and that impulse can be at any phase for example if in quadrature will create a quadrature error in the result)

What about the case of sending information specifically at the carrier via a DC offset... There's not much information to send.  In AM radio it provides a nice amplitude reference, so you know the difference between the transmitted audio getting quiet and the radio wave getting attenuated.  This is worthy of a separate question; it shouldn't be buried in the comments.

@Noha Did this answer your question?
